# What is the strength of the negative effect of Skruuia, Spirit of Scorn in Cookie Clicker?

Tags: cookie-clicker

Skruuia, Spirit of Scorn in the Cookie Clicker Pantheon has the downside:

> All golden cookies are wrath cookies with a greater chance of a negative effect

By how much is the chance of a negative effect different from usual? This detail isn't documented in the [Cookie Clicker wiki](http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Pantheon) (which for most other things is quite detailed).

Comment: Ah, it seems the kind of code digging that no one wants to do. I think nobody wants to research that, because you're supposed to *not click* Wrath Cookies when using Skruuia.

Comment: There is an advantage to doing that however, incase you need to try and trigger a clot for whatever reason, such as minimizing CPS before planting in your garden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skruuia adds "Clot" and "Ruin" each twice into the list of potential wrath cookie effects.

```
 if (me.wrath>0 && Game.hasGod && Game.hasGod('scorn')) list.push('clot','ruin cookies','clot','ruin cookies');
```

If we make a simple example, like 4 other positive effects in the list (Lucky, Elder frenzy, Cookie chain and Cookie storm), then the chance of getting "Clot" or "Ruin" raises from 33% (<sup>2</sup>/<sub>6</sub>) to 60% (<sup>2+4</sup>/<sub>6+4</sub> = 6/10).